# Is there a word in English to describe the descent of water or fluid out from a source?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word to describe the flow of a liquid downwards gently and continually from a source.

E.g. water being shot up from a jet fountain and then bending and flowing downwards.

Lava flowing out of a volcano.

See images.[image: Simple water fountain]

[image: Volcanic lava flow]

[image: Modern water fountain at night]

Comment: to arc out of something. The water is arcing out of the fountain.

Comment: The examples you give seem to be two different things. A steady flow, like a lava flow, does not involve arcing in the way the water does.

Comment: @GArthurBrown The lava comes up out of the ground and then flows down, so there is an upward and then downward trajectory; you just can't see it.

Comment: @Lambie I'd prefer to allow the poster to refine what they mean. Their clarification doesn't suggest that *going up* is any part of this "I'm looking for a word to describe the flow of a liquid downwards gently and continually from a source."

Comment: Spill, drain, drip, spout.

Comment: The most generic term I can think of is ***to surface***. Something must go ***upwards*** in order to "surface", and once it's done that *anywhere on earth*, it's still subject to gravity even after the force that made it rise no longer applies. We wouldn't use that term for ornamental fountains, but broadly speaking it works for surface outflows of subterranean water, oil, lava, etc.

Comment: @GArthurBrown The OP probably didn't even realize that both a fountain and a volcano have stuff arcing out of them. That is what they have in common: the upward trajectory, the zenith and then the downward one.

Comment: @Lambie I live literally within eye shot of several volcanoes one of which is almost always active...that thought never occurred to me...

Comment: Probably "pour" is the most general, but there are a lot of other verbs for specific contexts: trickle, sprinkle, shower, rain, flood, deluge, spew, ... one trick I use is look up *multiple* words in Moby Thesaurus and only print the intersection (since this is much better at limiting the results to a particular part of speech).

Comment: @Cascabel: After reading about lava just now, I'd be inclined to move if I were you. [Lava flows destroy everything in their path](https://www.usgs.gov/natural-hazards/volcano-hazards/lava-flows-destroy-everything-their-path)

Comment: Why not just say flow?

Comment: How did this get reopened without clarification?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Nah...earthquakes are considered more dangerous here. The worst volcanic effect we have had in the capitol is 'black rain'...

Comment: I think this should be closed as the OP provides no clarification.

Answer (score 13):

A good one is *Cascade*

What wonderful pictures you have.

From Collins English Thesaurus:
Cascade  (noun)  Definition; a cascade of falling water where there is a vertical or almost vertical step in a river "Angel Falls, the world's highest waterfall"
Synonyms: cascade, fall, cataract, chute, linn (Scottish)
Also; drop, gush, spout, flow, fountain, stream.

Cascade is not by definition violent. From a dictionary of waterfall terms;http://falzguy.com/waterfall.glossary.html
CASCADING   When a stream descends a very steep rock face somewhat smoothly or in a series of small individual drops, or any combination of these.

Comment: *Cascading* is a violent motion of water directly down that is not necessarily implied to be continuous.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Water actually doesn't fall straight down in a waterfall, it flows outwards and down in a parabolic arc.

Comment: The one term you don't mention says it precisely: to arc out.

Comment: "I'm looking for a word to describe the flow of a liquid downwards gently and continually from a source."

Comment: @GArthurBrown _Cascade_ is OP's best bet. It's hard sometimes to subsume multiple concepts into a single word: the usual verbs _gush_, _spurt_, _disembogue_, _ooze_,etc. would describe the manner in which water comes out of its source. A separate verb would be needed to describe the manner of its flow afterward.

Comment: @user405662 I think the existence of *flow* or *pour* belies this. As the example of the volcano demonstrates no arcing.